# Execute command with Excel macro and close cmd window

Tags: vba, excel, cmd

Here is what I'm trying right now:

```
Sub del_BJSFM_files()

Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /K" & "cd /d C:\UTAS-SA && del /f/s/q BJSFM > nul", vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

The problem is that the command window stays open.

I tried removing the "/K" but then the command doesn't execute properly.

Comment: Well don't you want `/c` instead of `/k`?

Comment: Options   
        ~/C     Run Command and then terminate

   /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.~
          This is useful for testing, to examine variables. As @shawnt00 pointed out , perhaps /c may be a better option.

Comment: Ok yea using /c works. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for it

```
Sub del_BJSFM_files()
  Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /c" & "cd /d C:\UTAS-SA && del /f/s/q BJSFM > nul", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

I replaced /k  with /c  and now it closes the window.

Answer (score 2):

**/C**     - Run Command and then terminate

**/K**     - Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt. This is useful for testing, to examine variables

[Source - https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)