# Close cmd window with vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a SQL request in my vba code

```
Set WSJ = VBA.CreateObject(“WScript.Shell)
WSJ.run “cmd.exe /C chcp 0000 & cd C:\oracle... “ & myPath & “.sql && exit”, 1,1
```

it worked perfect but recently stopped closing cmd window and not continue the process (it doesn't happen all the time, 1 or 2 times for day). There is no error, the last line is **«disconnected from the server»**, but the window does not close and the code does not continue to work.

is it possible to write in the code a check for closing cmd window after a minute or something like that? or configure sql to reach this line and close

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute command with Excel macro and close cmd window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685666/execute-command-with-excel-macro-and-close-cmd-window)

Answer (score 0):

please try with below code

```
   Sub closwWindow()
      Call Shell("cmd.exe /S /c" & "cd /d C:\UTAS-SA && del /f/s/q BJSFM > nul", vbNormalFocus)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As the return value of WScript.Shell.Run is not very useful, I've tried to do it in another way, but I only found a way to get this done from command prompt itself:

Using `Start`, I can start a command prompt with the title I'm giving it, like:

```
start "this is an interesting window" cmd.exe
```

As a result, a command prompt is started, having "this is an interesting window" as the title. You can then use `Tasklist` in order to find this, something like:

```
tasklist /V | findstr "this_is_an_interesting_window"
cmd.exe  8240 Console  6  3 636 K Running  DESKTOP-D0GIHSU\plop  0:00:00 this_is_an_interesting_window
```

From there you can retrieve the process ID (8240) in this case, and you can use `TaskKill` in order to kill it:

```
taskkill /FI "PID eq 8240"
SUCCESS: Sent termination signal to the process with PID 8240.
```

Good luck